# Class 'kartik\builder\Form' not found

Tags: kartik

Столкнулся с элементарным вопросом, но не могу его решить. Есть [yii2-builder](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-builder) который согласно документации устанавливается через `php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-builder "dev-master"` Запустил, установил, всё ок: создалась папка \vendor\kartik-v\yii2-builder с файлами. Есть файл вида:

```
<?php

use kartik\form\ActiveForm;
use kartik\builder\Form;

$form = ActiveForm::begin();
echo Form::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'form' => $form,
    'columns' => 2,
    'attributes' => [
        'username' => ['type'=>Form::INPUT_TEXT, 'options'=>['placeholder'=>'Enter username...']],
        'password' => ['type'=>Form::INPUT_PASSWORD, 'options'=>['placeholder'=>'Enter password...']],
        'rememberMe' => ['type'=>Form::INPUT_CHECKBOX],
    ]
]);
ActiveForm::end();
```

при клике в IDE на `kartik\form\ActiveForm` открывается файл \vendor\kartik-v\yii2-widget-activeform\src\ActiveForm.php, при клике на `use kartik\builder\Form` открывается файл \vendor\kartik-v\yii2-builder\src\Form.php, т.е. всё хорошо и правильно, но при открытии этого вида в браузере получаю ошибку `Class 'kartik\builder\Form' not found`.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не дохтур, конечно, но что если слэши написать в правильную сторону?

Comment: слеши написаны правильно

Comment: А на картинке - нет.

Comment: вы хотите сказать, что должно быть use kartik/form/ActiveForm;
use kartik/builder/Form; ?

Comment: Ну, не знаю, как должно быть в винде, но просто проверить.

Comment: так синтаксическая ошибка

Answer (score 0):

в vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php добавил

```
'kartik\\builder\\' => array($vendorDir . '/kartik-v/yii2-builder/src'),
```

в vendor/yiisoft/extensions.php добавил

```
  'kartik-v/yii2-builder' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'kartik-v/yii2-builder',
    'version' => '9999999-dev',
    'alias' => 
    array (
      '@kartik/builder' => $vendorDir . '/kartik-v/yii2-builder/src',
    ),
  ),
```

заработало. Вобщем, суть ошибки была в том, что композер папку скачал, в IDE всё срослось, но зависимости в этих файлах по какой-то причине не прописал.